# Optimize group by sub query in Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, subquery

It's quite a straight-forward query.

If I run the queries separately it is not that slow but when I combine them its very slow.

I'm not sure how to optimise it. I'm basically only wanting to show multiple refunds. So where `faultid` exists more than once.

```
SELECT 
    r.* 
FROM 
    faultrefunds_v2 r
WHERE 
    r.id IN (SELECT r1.id 
             FROM faultrefunds_v2 r1 
             GROUP BY faultid
             HAVING count(r1.faultid) > 1);
```

The results from explain are have been attached as an image

[image]

Comment: Is r.id the primary key?

Comment: yes, and faultid is the foreign key

Comment: I think the query you wrote doesn't answer the question. This is because once you've grouped by faultid you'll only return one r.id for that faultid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this qualifies rather as a re-writing than as an optimisation, but this is what I would try instead, anyway:

```
SELECT 
  r.* 
FROM faultrefunds_v2 r
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM faultrefunds_v2 r1 
  WHERE r1.faultid = r.faultid
    AND r1.id <> r.id
);
```

Comment: why is this much faster than the query I wrote?  they look quite similar?

Comment: Your query uses grouping, which is a relatively expensive operation, to begin with. Furthermore, a subquery of that kind is supposed to scan the entire table to build the row set to match against. My query, on the other hand, uses a semi-join (in the form of the `EXISTS` predicate). In a semi-join, matches for a row stop being searched for as soon as at least one is found, which you can guess may speed up the query dramatically in cases where many matches exist for some/most of the rows.

Comment: When using exist does it only work by using the same table (but with a different alias)?  How does it know what ID to link the tables with.

Comment: @Robbo_UK: You can use any (number of) tables in the EXISTS subquery, like in pretty much any other subquery, only bearing in mind that EXISTS (at least, according to SQL standards) ignores whatever columns you are trying to retrieve (hence you can often see `SELECT * FROM …` in the EXISTS subqueries, albeit some people find it more clear to have something like `SELECT NULL FROM …` or `SELECT 1 FROM …` or whatever works for them). What solely matters to the EXISTS predicate is whether the subquery returns any rows (at least one): if it does, the predicate evaluates to true, otherwise to false.

Answer (score 2):

`IN` clause the way you used it would be very slow, use `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT r.* FROM ( 
  SELECT r1.id AS id
  FROM faultrefunds_v2 r1 
  GROUP BY faultid
  HAVING count(r1.faultid) > 1
) AS ids
LEFT JOIN faultrefunds_v2 AS r
ON( ids.id = r.id )
```

Comment: this works, its very fast.  Can you please explain why the IN clause is slow with the way I used it so I can avoid doing it again?

Comment: MySql usually doesn't index the elements within the IN clause so it should compare id of each row in `r` table with all the ids found in the sub query every time. In my method MySql finds all the appropriate ids once then retrieves full row for each id in the outer query very quickly using the index.

Comment: This answer is the correct answer along side Andiry M response.  I cant accept two answers (although i think its possible to have two correct but different answers for the same question).

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is not answering the question. As I understand it, you should first get all faultid that have more than one associated id (row in the table). And then get all those rows (not just the faultId).

Try this:

```
select * from faultrefunds_v2
where faultId in (
    select faultId from faultrefunds_v2
    group by faultId
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: I think this is an improvement on my query, its more logical and explanatary.  But its still quite slow. given it +1